# Archimedean ordered field and non-expressible in first order logic

Tags: logic, model-theory

In Chang and Keisler's model theory, they define that an ordered field $(F,+_{F},\cdot,0_{F},1_{F},\le)$ is Archimedean iff for any two positive elements $a$, $b$ in $F$ there is an $n$ such that $b\le na$.

(Here the notation $na$ is an abbreviation for the term $a+_{F}\ldots+_{F}a$, $n$ times.)

And they say that this definition is not expressible in first order logic.
My question is why it is impossible to express the definition in first order logic. In $\mathrm{ZF}$, we can define recursively a function $f$ such that $\mathrm{dom}(f)=\omega$, $f(0)=a$ and $f(n+1)=f(n)+_{F}a$. So the definition can be formalized in $\mathrm{ZF}$. I don't know what I'm missing..

Comment: From the context, it's clear that they mean "not expressible in first order logic *in the language of ordered fields*."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Alex Kruckman says, the intended meaning is that this definition can't be expressed in the first-order language of ordered fields. The problem is that the first-order language of ordered fields does not obviously allow you to quantify over all positive integers $n$; you can talk about

$$na = \underbrace{a + \dots + a}_{n \text{ times}}$$

for any fixed $n$, but the first-order language of ordered fields $F$ only allows you to quantify over $F$, and doesn't obviously supply you with a way of talking about $\mathbb{N} \subset F$.

I say "obviously" because a priori there could be a clever trick that does it, but in fact there can't be such a trick. This is because the class of models of a first-order theory must be closed under [ultraproducts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraproduct), but it's possible for an ultraproduct of archimedean fields to be non-archimedean. For example the ultrapower $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}/U$ of countably many copies of $\mathbb{R}$ (the *nonstandard reals*) is non-archimedean: we can take $a = (1, 1, 1, \dots)$ and $b = (1, 2, 3, \dots)$ and then there is no positive integer $n$ such that $b \le na$ (in other words, $b$ is infinitely large compared to $a$).

**Ignorable additional comment:** You can extend the first-order theory of ordered fields to a two-sorted theory consisting of one sort for the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ and another sort for the field $F$, together with, say, an embedding $\mathbb{N} \hookrightarrow F$; this would allow you to talk about the operation $(n, a) \mapsto na$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a \in F$, and to quantify over $\mathbb{N}$. Now the problem is that it's impossible to write down axioms guaranteeing that the first sort is exactly $\mathbb{N}$ and not some larger nonstandard model of the natural numbers; for example, whatever axioms we write down, we can take an ultrapower of the pair $(\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{R})$ and we'll have infinitely large nonstandard natural numbers, so the ultrapower $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}/U$ will still be "archimedean" but with respect to the nonstandard natural numbers $\mathbb{N}^{\infty}/U$, not the standard ones. So this doesn't work either.

Comment: This leads to something funny I don't think I've noticed before: the same ultrapower argument applies to ZF! So there can be models of ZF in which the natural numbers are nonstandard, and in particular they can be *externally* uncountable. Funny stuff.

Comment: Makkai's definability theorem (as called in [Lurie's course](https://www.math.ias.edu/~lurie/278x.html), first lecture) even says that this is almost an equivalence for a property to be first-order definable: the models must be closed by elementary extension/submodels and by ultraproducts. Right?

Comment: @Ideophage: I believe that some statement of this form must be true but I don’t think it follows from what’s written there.

Comment: In theorem 12 (Makkai Definability Theorem) [here](https://www.math.ias.edu/~lurie/278xnotes/Lecture1-Overview.pdf), we take $\tilde{M} \subseteq M^0$ to be $\{\star\}$ if $M$ satisfies the property and $\emptyset$ otherwise. I think it works...

Comment: @Ideophage: what's $\star$? What if a model has automorphisms with no fixed points?

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought that in the statement of the pdf I linked to, there was an implicit variable $n$ and that $\tilde{M}$ was a subset of $M^n$. I stated the case $n=0$ but I see only the case $n=1$ is really in the pdf, right. I just suppose the general statement follows from Makkai duality but cannot affirm that yet...